# Image is not display from server

Tags: ios, iphone

hello i am trying to fetch image from server in view .
The link is here

```
(image_file_name":"SPORTS DAY.jpg","image_file_path":"/file?key=AMIfv94Kr4jhI3rvj_91litYhNea5Z0B0gtf5sT-yyPlleesStjvlN-F7OnE3ZNq2Zsz_M41UduLEi6oWjY1wckzf6zMd-2HKptNAiAmHpoUIT2rzIcbGThFR8VXAadjm5E-il-uorOaNcWWmyyy8ykveoxwI-swvw&download=false"})
```

and my code is here

```
 UIImage *img =[UIImage imageNamed:[NSURL URLWithString:[(NSMutableDictionary *)[SharedPreferenceUtil getNSObject:STUDENT_DATA_JSON] valueForKey:@"image_file_name"]]];

 cell.imageView.image=img;
```

please solve this.

Comment: The `UIImage imageNamed:` takes a NSString and not a NSURL parameter. You need to first download the image from your server (download to file or to memory), and then instantiate your image with the file (in case of download to file) or the data buffer (in case of download to memory).

Comment: @AbhishekPathak you just take URL of image from server and then fetch image form that url.

Comment: Simply take your URL from JSON response and check it in browser, whether URL is correct or not, I mean that response URL should show image in browser.

Answer (score 1):

The method `imageNamed:` of `UIImage` you are using loads the local image, i.e. image that's contained in you app's bundle. In order to load image from the server, you have to use different techniques, like:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL urlWithString:{image_url}]]; 
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

and then use image on image view. There are actually a lot more techniques to load image from server. Hope this helps, Good Luck!

Comment: ok i will try this hope it will work f

Comment: This is the correct answer, if it doesn't work then you're doing it wrong and you should say it so we can help a bit more. :)